# Flip character horizontally and print it with java

Tags: java, character, flip, mirror

What I'm trying to do is receive a character from the keyboard, for example 'a' and flip that letter horizontally and print it out. I have searched everywhere for flipped images but there doesn't seem to exist any method to do that. Can anyone help me? I'm trying to do this in Java btw. 
Thanks a lot in advance, if you need more details ask me in the comment section.

p.s. I can't show you the desired output because I couldn't find any flipped characters online. 
The concept is the same as with an image horizontal flip, but I want to do this with characters.

Comment: I dont think there is any way to do something like this unless you get a picture of every symbol on the keyboard, manually do the image rotation, and then map those images to keyboard events corresponding the proper key press. Anybody else have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

You might try something like creating a `BufferedImage`, getting its `Graphics2D` and setting its `AffineTransform` to `AffineTransform.scale(-1, 1)`, and then using the `Graphics2D`'s `drawString` method.  You're not going to be able to print that to the console -- I don't think what you're suggesting is possible at all, printing to the console -- but that technique would produce an image for you.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation using images; not sure if there's a way to flip the characters themselves.

```
import java.io.*;

public class RotateAndFlip {


    static JPEGImage rotate90(JPEGImage inputImage) {
    JPEGImage outputImage = new JPEGImage(inputImage.getHeight(),
                          inputImage.getWidth());

    // Code to make outputImage into an image that is a 
    // 90 degree rotation of inputImage

    return outputImage;
    }
    static JPEGImage rotate180(JPEGImage inputImage) {
    return rotate90(rotate90(inputImage));
    }

    static JPEGImage rotate270(JPEGImage inputImage) {
    return rotate90(rotate90(rotate90(inputImage)));
    }

    static JPEGImage flipHorizontal(JPEGImage inputImage) {
    JPEGImage outputImage = new JPEGImage(inputImage.getWidth(),
                          inputImage.getHeight());

    // Code to make outputImage into an image that is a 
    // horizontal flip of inputImage

    return outputImage;
    }

    static JPEGImage flipVertical(JPEGImage inputImage) {
    return rotate90(flipHorizontal(rotate270(inputImage)));
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
    /* Check that the user has provided the right number of arguments */
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Usage: java JPEGCopy <source JPEG file> " + 
                   "<target JPEG file>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /* Create an empty image. We will read an image from a file into
       this object */
    JPEGImage imageOne = new JPEGImage();

    /* Try to open the file. This may cause an exception if the name 
       given is not a valid JPEG file so we need to catch the exceptions */
    try {
        imageOne.read(args[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* An exception has been thrown. This is usually because the file
           either does not exist, or is not a JPEG image */
        System.out.println("Error reading file " + args[0]);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /* Make a new image to store the results in */
    JPEGImage imageTwo = new JPEGImage();


    /* Rotate by 90 degrees and write to a file */
    imageTwo = rotate90(imageOne);
    try {
        imageTwo.write("rotate90.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing file rotate90.jpg");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /* Rotate by 180 degrees and write to a file */
    imageTwo = rotate180(imageOne);
    try {
        imageTwo.write("rotate180.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing file rotate180.jpg");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /* Rotate by -90 degrees and write to a file */
    imageTwo = rotate270(imageOne);
    try {
        imageTwo.write("rotate270.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing file rotate270.jpg");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /* Flip horizontally and write to a file */
    imageTwo = flipHorizontal(imageOne);
    try {
        imageTwo.write("flipHorizontal.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing file flipHorizontal.jpg");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /* Flip vertically and write to a file */
    imageTwo = flipVertical(imageOne);
    try {
        imageTwo.write("flipVertical.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing file flipVertical.jpg");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    }
}
```

Here: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~smx/IVIPracticals/exercise1.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. I think the simplest way to do this would be to get a set of images of all the letters and symbols, use flip them using any conventional graphics software -- PaintShopPro, PhotoShop, whatever -- save the images as a bunch of individual GIF or PNG files, and then retrieve the appropriate one when you need it.

If you really want to do the flipping within the Java program, I think the key is to:

1. Create a BufferedImage object
2. Call createGraphics on it to get a Graphics object.
3. Write the character or characters to this Graphics object using drawString
4. Then you can manipulate the image however you want using getRGB and setRGB. Basically you'd want to traverse the image from top to center swapping pixels from the top half to the bottom half.

I guess if you want it to work with any font, in many sizes, etc, you'd have to do it in a program.

*Update*

Based on your comment of Jan 30, it appears that you mean that you don't want to generate the reversed image yourself, but rather you want to find a reversed image among the Unicode character set. I'm afraid that, to the best of my knowledge, Unicode does not include a reverse image of every character. It includes a few that are symbols in their own right and that have specific meanings. For example, Unicode has a backwards capital E at U+2203, but if you look at other characters with nearby Unicode code points you'll see that they are various mathematical symbols. A backwards E is "in there" because it's a math symbol meaning "there exists", not because the inventors of Unicode are giving mirror images of every character.

I certainly don't have the complete Unicode code set memorized so I can't swear that there's no such set of characters in there somewhere, but I really doubt it. The point of Unicode was supposed to be to give a way to represent all the alphabets in the world and a robust set of commonly-used symbols. They very deliberately did NOT include separate code points for things like italic and bold, or for different sizes, because those things should be handled by selecting a different font, not a different set of Unicode code points. It would thus be very surprising if they added mirror images of every symbol. That would be contrary to the philosophy of Unicode. And if they did that, then why not upside down versions? Why not rotated 90 degrees? Etc etc.

So I think the short answer to your question is, It can't be done. There are no such Unicode characters.

Comment: I obviously know how to do that. there's plenty of tutorials and forums for this task anyway... I'm not that stupid. what I'm trying is mirror the CHARACTER, not its IMAGE. That is, finding the unicode for every letter like \u0258 for ɘ (which is the mirror image of e) that's what i'm trying to accomplish. for the whole alphabet though.

Comment: There is no way we can gauge 'how stupid' you are short of your fleshing out the question to indicate what you know.  Do *you* know how *psychic* we are?  -1

Comment: what i DO know is your cocky attitude of "i don't really know what you're trying to achieve here". If that was of any help to answering my question, I would have included it on my post. :)

Comment: Hmm, that wasn't meant to be cocky, but a simple statement of fact. I am not clear on what your goal is, so it is difficult to say if any given advice is helpful. Whether it is your fault or mine, I do not believe we have fully communicated. As I, and I presume most other participants on this forum, don't know you personally, we have no way to know if you are a total novice or the world's leading Java expert. If every time someone says, "I'm sorry, I don't understand you, can you please explain further" you insist on taking it as an insult, you will spend a lot of time unnecessarily angry. :-)